# Where is ntdll.dll?

Tags: windows, assembly, memory, immunity-debugger

I am trying to get the base address of `ntdll.dll` over the `PEB`. So, what I did was to dump the `PEB` (`d fs:[30]`). Then, I tried to get to `PEB_LDR_DATA` over the offset `0xC`. Over the offset `0x1C` of `PEB_LDR_DATA` I found the the pointer of `InInitializationOrderModuleList` and I was told that I can find the `ntdll.dll` address there. And that I should first find the address of `kernel32.dll` (which is always the second entry). So, I was able to find the address of `kernel32.dll` but it seems like I can't find the address of `ntdll.dll`.

```
00251ED8  .ܛὈ%Ậ%ὐ%Ẵ%.....@ᐴ@怀.TVٜڔ倀...뉨粘뉨粘趨即....ꮫꮫꮫꮫ......ܨ‐%Ỡ%‘%Ứ%
00251F58  †%Ẽ%.粑Ⱘ粒怀:Ȉ퀨粘⅘粓䀄耈..니粘니粘뾿䠂....ꮫꮫꮫꮫ......ܵC:\WINDOWS\system32\
00251FD8  kernel32.dll.ꮫꮫꮫꮫﻮﻮﻮ......߁⅐%Ὀ%⅘%ὐ%Ⅰ%὘%.粀똾粀耀@Bᾰ%Ῐ%䀄耈..늰粘늰粘뿀䠂
00252058  ....ꮫꮫꮫꮫ.....ߎC:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b
002520D8  9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375\MSVCR90.dll.ꮫꮫꮫꮫ.....ߩẬ%‐%
00252158  Ẵ%‘%Ẽ%†%.硒ⵀ硔　.¾À⁸%℠%䀆逈..닀粘닀粘㷎䜱....ꮫꮫꮫꮫ....ߊ.ᓮîŸ%Ÿ%ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮ
```

This is the part where I have found the `kernel32.dll`. But in the fact of that this a linked list. Shouldn't I be able to find `ntdll.dll` too?

When, I open up the window of "Executable Modules" I can see the `ntdll.dll` but it seem I am not able to find the base address inside of the `Struct`.

Please tell me if you need clarification or if I am grievously mistaken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code below will set `EAX` to the image base address of `ntdll.dll`:

```
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR FS:[30]     ; EAX = PEB
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0C] ; EAX = PEB->Ldr
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+1C] ; EAX = PEB->Ldr.InInitializationOrderModuleList.Flink
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+8]  ; EAX = image base of ntdll (LDR_MODULE's BaseAddress)
```

Based on your question above, it seems like you understand everything through the `MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+1C]` instruction. Since `ntdll.dll` is the first module loaded, it's the first `LDR_MODULE` entry in `InInitializationOrderModuleList`. So with `EAX` pointing to `PEB->Ldr.InInitializationOrderModuleList.Flink`, `[EAX+0]` points to the list entry's `Flink`, `[EAX+4]` points to the list entry's `Blink`, and `[EAX+8]` is the `BaseAddress` value of the first `LDR_MODULE` entry (`ntdll.dll`'s `LDR_MODULE`).

This image from http://blog.csdn.net/programmingring/article/details/11357393 may help:[image: diagram]

When `EAX` is set to `PEB->Ldr.InInitializationOrderModuleList.Flink`, it's pointing to the orange `Flink` in the first `LDR_MODULE` above. It's followed by the `Blink` at `[EAX+4]`, and the "`DllBase`" (`BaseAddress`) at `[EAX+8]`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to see it in Windbg.

You can follow this walk through for each pointer points to successive `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` the output is from `calc.exe`.

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c))))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)))))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c))))))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)))))))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll"
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c))))))))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING ""
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY -y Full poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(poi(@$peb+c)+c)))))))))))))
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe"
```

**an alternate representation of the above method**

```
lkd> dt nt!_ldr_data_table_entry -y Full @@c++(@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe"
lkd> dt nt!_ldr_data_table_entry -y Full @@c++(@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll"
lkd> dt nt!_ldr_data_table_entry -y Full @@c++(@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink->Flink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll"
lkd> dt nt!_ldr_data_table_entry -y Full @@c++(@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink->Flink->Flink->Flink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll"
```