# How to dynamically load address of USER32.DLL in shellcode?

Tags: windows, shellcode

Assuming I'm injecting a shellcode into a Windows GUI application, I know I could:

- Gets kernel32.dll base address through the PEB (Process Environment Block);
- Finds address of LoadLibrary;
- Call LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
- Finally call GetProcAddress.

This is the classic way and that's what I would do, however I'd like to know if there's a better/improved/faster/clever/different/smaller or simpler way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `user32.dll` is already loaded in the process's address space (and I assume it is given that you said it's a Windows GUI application), you can walk the [`PEB_LDR_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813708.aspx) structure in order to find the base address of `user32.dll`:

- [KERNEL32 image base address on Windows Seven](https://ringzer0.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/kernel32-image-base-address-on-windows-seven/)
- [Understanding the PEB Loader
  Data Structure](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_the_Peb_Loader_Data_List.html)
- [Where is ntdll.dll?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4465/where-is-ntdll-dll)

Comment: Do you have sample code? I'm not sure I understood know to identify user32.dll base address

Comment: http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=4479.msg47967#msg47967

Comment: Excelent code, well documented. Thank you